# what's the expression for an argument that is not easy to talk on as it's likely to offend someone

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I used the phrase 'slippery slope' to mention such an argument that is not easy to talk on because it's not possible to say a word without offending someone. Later I noticed that 'slippery slope' was the wrong decision. Which phrase suits in this case?

Examples might be:

cleavage in workplace

using country flags in artworks to protest

filming porno in churchs

using ezan sound in a metal music context.

The aforementioned examples are controversial, it's like everyone is right and it's so hard to draw on a conclusion.

Comment: Maybe "hot-button topic"? but "filming porno in churches" doesn't really seem like an issue that many people will be queueing up to defend to me.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Examples such as "cleavage in workplace" and "ezan sound" are incomprehensible to me.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "cleavage in workplace" is about women wearing low cut garments at work. Ezan is the Islamic call to prayer and metal music is a genre of rock music with heavy and loud guitars and drums.  Whether and why these might (or might not) be controversial is not relevant.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for clarifying. If those meanings are what OP intended, then they should be explained in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *sensitive issue*.  This is not about the argument itself, but about the topic being argued about.

A sensitive issue is a topic that people may have strong feelings about and be willing to argue about.  It is not easy to bring up a sensitive issue because you may hurt someone's feelings or trigger them in some way:

> John tentatively raised the sensitive issue of the staff dress code in the weekly meeting, and as he feared it provoked a bitter argument.